# Android onFocusChange AND onClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, listener, onclicklistener

I am trying to call a certain function consistently when EditText is clicked. The problem is that if I implement onClick then onClick does not get called the first time EditText is clicked and when I add onFocusChange to fix this the listener that was added afterwards to the same EditText doesn't seem to work. The user should also be able to type into the EditText after focusing or clicking on it. OnTextChanged is not an option. Can you even have two listeners like this?

I set the receiverEditText variable in onCreateView and call addListeners in onResume.

Java:

```
public void addListeners()
    {
        receiverEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                doTheThingFunction();
            }
        });

       View.OnFocusChangeListener listener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
            {
                doTheThingFunction();
            }
        };
        receiverEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(listener);
    }
```

XML:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageReceiver"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:hint="@string/recipient"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:focusable="true">
            <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Waltari I have created demo to check focus state of some edittextview.
Check code.

Use this in onCreate() of activity.

```
EditText messageReceiver = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageReceiver);

        messageReceiver.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Focus gained", 1)
                            .show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Focuse released",
                            1).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

In your **XML file**

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/messageReceiver"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:hint="recipient"
        android:padding="3dp" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:hint="recipient"
        android:padding="3dp" >
    </EditText>
```

This gives me focus gain release events of messageReceiver.

Focuse will be gained when you show cursor on  Edittext with id "messageReceiver"  and when you click another edittext than focus released of "messageReceiver" is called.

So that means you have to manage focus release when you work is done.

Comment: I tried your code, but it still doesn't work with the onClick listener. I also want to call the function on onClick listener as well as onFocus change.

Comment: May i know why you want click listener on Edittext box ? You can use textWatcher .

Comment: You can call function in on focus gain which you want to execute onClick.

Comment: I've created a dropdown list using edittext and a listview... Whenever the user clicks the edittext the listview should appear. The listview also updates everytime the edittext text changes.

Comment: I can get the onClickListener working and I can get the onFocusChange listener working. It's just when I implement both at the same time the onFocusChangeListener breaks :(

Comment: Can I know what actually you want to do with click and focus listeners? Why you need both of them?

Comment: Because onClickListener does not register the click the first time I click the EditText. The only solution I found was to also add a onFocusChangeListener. Sorry, for being so vague.